# Reading/Writing FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception, access-denied, printwriter

Every time my program tries to read or write a file, I get the following message:

```
[System]: LoadConfig >> Config file is missing or corrupt!
C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Run.config (Access is denied)
```

I looked this up on the internet, and everyone that had this issue was simply trying to read a directory, it was the same way for writing files. I double checked everything, but it continues to `throw` an `exception`.
I tried running the program as administrator, but that didn't do anything :/

If you look at my code, you can see I'm logging everything. I will provide a copy of my log.

**This is my reading method:**

```
public static ArrayList<String> readConfig(){

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(searchForConfig(baseDir));
        //searchForConfig(baseDir) always will return a file.

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            list.add(sc.nextLine());
        }

        sc.close();

        return list;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.addElement("[System]: LoadConfig >> Config file is missing or corrupt!");
        Logger.addElement(e.getMessage());
    }

    list.add("Nothing");

    return list;
}
```

**My writing method is the following:**

```
public static boolean createNewFile(String Name, String Path, ArrayList<String> Content, boolean override){

    File file2 = new File(Path + dash + Name);

    if(override == false & file2.exists()){

        Name += "1";

    }else{
        if(override == true & file2.exists()){
            file2.delete();
        }
    }

    if(!(Name.indexOf(".") > 0)){
        Name += ".cardinal";
    }

    File file = new File(Path);
    if(!file.isDirectory() | !file.exists()){
        Logger.addElement("[FileWriter]: NewFile >> New file path is invalid.");
        Logger.addElement("[FileWriter]: NewFile >> Creating dirs at path.");
        file.mkdirs();
    }


    try {

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Path + dash + Name, "UTF-8");

        for(int i = 0; i < Content.size(); i++){
            pw.println(Content.get(i));
        }
        Logger.addElement("[FileWriter]: NewFile >> Creating file " + Name + " at " + Path + dash);
        pw.close();
        return true;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.addElement("[FileWriter]: NewFile >> FileNotFoundException.");
        Logger.addElement(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.addElement("[FileWriter]: NewFile >> UnsupportedEncodingException.");
        Logger.addElement(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I changed my logger to record `stacktraces` and got  more info. It's a bit lengthy, but everything is there:

```
[System]: Config >> Searching for config in base directory...
[System]: LoadConfig >> Config file is missing or corrupt!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Run.config (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.LoadConfig.readConfig(LoadConfig.java:21)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:9)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preInit(Init.java:20)
    at com.orlow.base.Main.main(Main.java:10)
[System]: Config >> Searching for config in base directory...
[System]: LoadConfig >> Config file is missing or corrupt!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Run.config (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.LoadConfig.readConfig(LoadConfig.java:21)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.Config.checkConfig(Config.java:13)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preInit(Init.java:20)
    at com.orlow.base.Main.main(Main.java:10)
[preInit]: Logger >> Starting logger...
[preInit]: Tests >> Testing config...
[System]: Config >> Searching for config in base directory...
[System]: LoadConfig >> Config file is missing or corrupt!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Run.config (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.LoadConfig.readConfig(LoadConfig.java:21)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preTests(Init.java:62)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preInit(Init.java:22)
    at com.orlow.base.Main.main(Main.java:10)
[preInit]: Config >> Config file is corrupt.
[System]: SaveConfig >> Replacing Config file...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Run.config (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.DataStorage.Files.createNewFile(Files.java:98)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.SaveConfig.replaceCorruptConfig(SaveConfig.java:26)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.Config.getConfigMode(Config.java:32)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.Config.getBuildPath(Config.java:77)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preTests(Init.java:68)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preInit(Init.java:22)
    at com.orlow.base.Main.main(Main.java:10)
[preInit]: Config >> Config file is corrupt.
[System]: SaveConfig >> Replacing Config file...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Run.config (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.DataStorage.Files.createNewFile(Files.java:98)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.SaveConfig.replaceCorruptConfig(SaveConfig.java:26)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.Config.getConfigMode(Config.java:32)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preTests(Init.java:74)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preInit(Init.java:22)
    at com.orlow.base.Main.main(Main.java:10)
[preInit]: Config >> Config file is corrupt.
[System]: SaveConfig >> Replacing Config file...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Run.config (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.DataStorage.Files.createNewFile(Files.java:98)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.SaveConfig.replaceCorruptConfig(SaveConfig.java:26)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.Config.getConfigMode(Config.java:32)
    at com.orlow.base.FileSystem.Config.Config.getLogPath(Config.java:126)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preTests(Init.java:80)
    at com.orlow.base.Init.Init.preInit(Init.java:22)
    at com.orlow.base.Main.main(Main.java:10)
[preInit]: Config >> Log path is set to C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Logs
[preInit]: Tests >> Config >> Config test was successful.
[preInit] Tests >> Testing file writer...
[FileWriter]: NewFile >> Creating file firstTestFile.cardinal at C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Data\
[FileWriter]: NewFile >> Creating file secondTextFile.cardinal at C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\Data\
[FileWriter]: NewFile >> Creating file thirdTestFile.cardinal at C:\Users\Cardinal System\Desktop\Peter\Programming\Java\Eclipse\Workspaces\Main Workspace\TestSkills\
[FileWriter]: NewFile >> Creating file forthTestFile.cardinal at C:\Users\Cardinal System\Desktop\Peter\Programming\Java\Eclipse\Workspaces\Main Workspace\TestSkills\
[preInit] Tests >> File writer test was successful.
[Init]: Console >> Rendering console GUI...
[System]: Console >> Type "?" for help.
```

Comment: maybe change `&` to `&&` and `|` to `||`

Comment: and change `if(!file.isDirectory() | !file.exists()){` to `if(!file.isDirectory() && !file.exists()){`

Comment: in other words debug your code

Comment: are you executing as an run as administrator. Right click the `OrlowBase` folder and in security tab give this folder as a write-permission.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I ran the program as administrator, so that shouldn't be the issue... Also, I want this to work on computers other than my own, so changing folder permissions isn't an option :/

Comment: @ScaryWombat What is the difference? I'll try next time I can.

Comment: Instead of cropping the top off the stack trace please post the whole thing, *including* the class and message. Impossible to follow otherwise.

Comment: @EJP Sorry about that, seems like `e.getStackTrace();` doesn't work. This would be a lot easier if people would answer my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623922/redirect-console-to-printstream-and-system-out)... I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. Can I now note that you shouldn't provide your own error messages: you should use the one in the exception. The file is neither missing nor corrupt.

Comment: @EJP I do know that... That error msg is only supposed to be displayed if the file is actually missing. It is for when the program is finished. But because it can't read the file, it thinks it is missing.

Comment: This could be due to the file is already locked by another thread. Can try using FileLock to aquire the lock before use which blocks until done and release after use. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible for usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the privileges for the user on the Orlowbase folder. 
When I deny the privileges for read/write/total control I got the exception you show, when I allow them, your program runs fine.

[image]

Comment: Although I was able to resolve this issue without changing the folder permissions, you still put the most effort into getting a good answer, so you get the bounty :)

Answer (score -1):

- It might be a permission issue. As what user you are running the application? Some user other than 'Cardinal System'? Check read/write access to `C:\Users\Cardinal System\AppData\Roaming\OrlowBase\*`
- Don't swallow stacktrace while catching FileNotFoundException. It might lead you to underlying cause.

UPDATE:
'AppData' is user specific folder and only accessible by the user and administrator. See more information here: 
[Can any user access the %APPDATA% folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617594/can-any-user-access-the-appdata-folder)

Comment: I ran the program as administrator, so that shouldn't be the issue... Also, I want this to work on computers other than my own, so changing folder permissions isn't an option :/ about AppData, Minecraft is java based an has access to AppData,  despite its lack of elevated privileges

Comment: I tested createNewFile() method it creates file without error on my machine. Can you share code for searchForConfig() method? And what's "basedir" path? Your log does not have any Path/dir related information for this method!